# Как оставить список раскрытым, если в нем отмечен checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"> {{ $attribute->title }}
        <i class="sidebar-menu-arrow fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            @foreach($values as $value)
                @if($attribute->id==$value->attribute_id)
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="filter[{{$attribute->id}}][{{ $value->id }}]" type="checkbox" value="1"
                                {{empty(request()->filter[$attribute->id][$value->id]) ? '' : 'checked'}} />
                        {{ $value->value }}
                    </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Состояние checkbox`ов запоминается после обновления страницы, переходов на другие страницы. Есть простой код jquery, который раскрывает/скрывает список

```
var $sidebarArrow = $('.sidebar-menu-arrow');

$sidebarArrow.click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Как при загрузке страницы раскрыть все списки, в которых отмечен какой либо checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам  нужно отобразить элементы с классом `sub-menu`, которые имеют вложенные отмеченные чекбоксы

```
$('.sub-menu:has(:checked)').show();
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $sidebarArrow = $('.sidebar-menu-arrow');

  $sidebarArrow.click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
  });
  
  $('.sub-menu:has(:checked)').show();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <i class="sidebar-menu-arrow fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true">1</i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" /> 1.1
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" /> 1.2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <i class="sidebar-menu-arrow fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true">2</i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 2.1
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" /> 2.2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <i class="sidebar-menu-arrow fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true">3</i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 3.1
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 3.2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```